# dockerized app needs to interact with other dockers over localhost

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-network

I have an app that launches a docker container and automates a few of the routines.
Now I have dockerized this app which is not able to talk to other containers over localhost. I tried setting 
    --network host
when launching the container and now not able to access the containerized webapp over localhost:.

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you running those workloads with an orchestrator (e.g., Swarm or Kubernetes)?

Comment: Right now no Docker swarm or Kubernetes. The problem is the webapp is accessible within the container (curl localhost) but from browser when I use localhost:port it doesn't show the webpage. The issue appears when i use `--network host` when starting the container

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` won't work. Suppose, you are running a VM and try to talk to your host/ other VMs running in your machine. If you call localhost from one of the VMs, it's localhost for that VM only, not to your host. So, you won't be able to talk from one VM to another by calling localhost. Docker works same in regard to the localhost. You have two options,

1. Use a network
   If you are using network, create a network and add all the containers to that network. This is the new suggested way by docker.

   ```
   docker network create <your-network-name>
   docker run --network <your-network-name> --name <container-name1> <image>
   docker run --network <your-network-name> --name <container-name2> <image>
   ```

   Then use the container name (container-name1) to talk to that service from other service (container-name2).
2. Use `--link` option

Or you could use `--link` option, which is a legacy system for docker. Docker docs says, unless you have a specific reason to use, don't use `--link` anymore.

```
docker run --name <container1> <image>
docker run --name <container2> <image>
```

You could use `container1` to talk from `container2` and vice versa. You could use these container name in places like DB host, etc.

Answer (score 0):

did you try creating a common bridge network and attach your containers to the same network:

create network :- 
docker network create *networkname*

and then in docker run command add this switch --network=*networkname*

Answer (score 0):

I figured it later after going over a lot of other documents.

Step 1: install docker inside the container. Added following line to my dockerfile

```
RUN curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Step 2: provide volume-mapping in `docker run` command

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Now hosts' docker commands are accessible from within my current container and without changing the --network for current docker container, I'm able to access other containers over localhost